# .each() not iterating properly

Tags: jquery, loops, html-table, jquery-selectors, each

I have been struggling with this issue for a few hours now without understanding the behaviour I have got. I did not found this issue on any other post (although I have found many related to the `.each()` method).

Anyway here I am:

**This is the HTML I what to iterate upon:**

```
<input type="text" id="investment" /><br />
<table id="fundTable">
        <tr> 
             <td class="rentability"> <span class="someClass"> 0.12 </span> </td>
             <td class="absoluteResult"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
             <td class="rentability"> <span class="someClass"> 0.24  </span> </td>
             <td class="absoluteResult"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            ...
</table>
```

The idea is: the user will enter a value in the textField `#investment`.
`onChange`, JQuery will populate the `.absoluteResult` table column by multiplying the user input by the `.rentability` value.

**Here is the JQuery part then:**

```
$('#investment').change(function() {
        var investment = $('#investment').val(),
            currentlyDisplayedRentability,
            updatedAbsoluteResult

        $('#fundTable tr').each(function(index, tableRow) {
            currentlyDisplayedRentability = $(tableRow + "span").html()
            currentlyDisplayedRentability = parseFloat(currentlyDisplayedRentability)
            updatedAbsoluteResult = currentlyDisplayedRentability * investment
            $(tableRow + "td[class=absoluteResult]").html(updatedAbsoluteResult)
        })
    })
```

What happens is that all `.absoluteResult` rows are populated using the value of the first row of the `.rentability` column. 
Only one value is used for all the pultiplication. It is as if `.each()` is iterating correctly on one column (`.absoluteResult`) and not on the other (`.rentability`).

I do not understand why.

Comment: I don't see a table/tbody with the id `#fundTable` in your code. So this makes no sense: `$('#fundTable tr').each( ... );`

Comment: The `tableRow` variable is not a string, it is the current element. You probably meant $("span", tableRow), or $(tableRow).find("span").

Comment: @biziclop is right. What's happened here is that you have not performed sufficient divide-and-conquer debugging, so have jumped to the conclusion that `each` is not iterating properly when, in fact, you're _completely_ reliant on a complex piece of code to test that iteration. If something's wrong in that code (and something is) then your entire test breaks. Instead, you should have `console.log`ged some information about the current object inside of `.each`, in order to rule out iteration issues as the cause of your problem.

Comment: you're also selecting on a table with id "fundTable" - I see no such table in your html sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#investment').change(function() {
        var investment = parseFloat($('#investment').val());

        $('table tr').each(function() {
            var $tr = $(this);
            var rentability = parseFloat($tr.find('.someClass').text());

            $tr.find('.absoluteResult').html(investment * rentability);
        })
    })
```

code: http://jsfiddle.net/qYSAH/1/

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is in the way you are using selectors to search within each table row; instead of

```
$(tableRow + "span").html()
```

try

```
$(tableRow).find("span").html()
```

Answer (score 2):

This works..

```
$('#investment').bind('keyup', function() {
var a = $(this).val();
if (!isNaN(parseFloat(a)) && isFinite(a)) {
    $('table tr').each(function() {
        var x = $(this).find('td.rentability .someClass').html();
        $(this).find('.absoluteResult').html(x * a);
    });
}
else { $('.absoluteResult').html(''); }
});
```

Here is the fiddle to check  http://jsfiddle.net/BcjMj/